# JQuery Colorbox in IE6 - missing border

Tags: jquery, border, colorbox, internet-explorer-6

Colorbox is a jquery plugin that works like a lightbox, it has an automatic border already but this border doesn't seem to show up for me in IE6, [this is](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/colorbox.css) their CSS as you can see near the bottom is where all the border ie6 styles are:

```
/*
  The following provides PNG transparency support for IE6
*/
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderTopLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderTopCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderTopRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderMiddleLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight{background:url(/images/colorbox/ie6/borderMiddleRight.png);}

.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight {
_behavior: expression(this.src = this.src ? this.src : this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.split('"')[1], this.style.background = "none", this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" + this.src + ", sizingMethod='scale')");
}
```

Comment: *gasp* You spoke that name of the browser that shall not be named.

Comment: My question is how do I get the border to show?
I hate IE6 so much and I wish I didn't have to support it! But alas the stupid large corporations still use this stupid browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The png fix thing in the CSS I pasted above is what broke it in IE6, once I removed all the code above it worked! Weird huh?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in IE6.  The problem you are having (I'm assuming with a site that you did not link to, and not the colorbox' examples page) is that the background images are not in the directory that the CSS expects them to be in.  Double check your file paths.